# -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug not working in IntelliJ IDEA JVM options

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying Kotlin's coroutines with [official guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) using IntelliJ IDEA on Mac OS. In [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#debugging-coroutines-and-threads) section there's an advice to use `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` JVM option to get detailed log output. What I did is I opened 'Help/Edit custom VM options...' and in the opened idea.vmoptions file I added  `-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug` line.

**idea.vmoptions** content after edit:

```
    # custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug
```

But after running the code again the output is:

```
[main] I'm computing a piece of the answer
[main] I'm computing another piece of the answer
[main] The answer is 42

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Whereas expected output is:

```
[main @coroutine#2] I'm computing a piece of the answer
[main @coroutine#3] I'm computing another piece of the answer
[main @coroutine#1] The answer is 42
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>Help > Edit custom VM options...</kbd> menu option lets you set the VM options for the execution of IntelliJ *itself*.

To set the options for your own application, you need to edit the *Run/Debug Configurations*. These can be found under <kbd>Run > Edit Configurations...</kbd> in the menu.

Selecting this option opens the following window which lets you set the VM options for your application(s):

[image: IntelliJ Run/Debug Configurations]

Comment: Be careful, after " =" not have redundant space ...Indeed like  “-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=on”